# Select-Object on nested collections

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm writing a Powershell cmdlet to list changesets from TFS. I successfully query TFS and get a collection of changesets but want to return simplified objects that contain only a few properties. I can do that using `Select-Object` like this...

```
$changesets | Select-Object ChangeSetId, Owner, Comment
```

The last property I would like to add is the `Changes` property which is an array of changes. I would like to simplify those objects as well. I'm trying this but it doesn't return what I want...

```
$changesets | Select-Object `
    ChangeSetId,
    Owner,
    Comment,
    @{Name="Changes"; Expression={ $_.Changes | Select-Object ChangeType, ServerItem }}
```

Is there a way to handle nested collections with `Select-Object`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your can use `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object` cmdlet. It will expand collection and add selected properties from parent object to child objects:

```
$changesets | Select-Object ChangeSetId, Owner, Comment,
    @{Name="Changes"; Expression={ $_.Changes | Select-Object ChangeType, ServerItem }} |
Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Changes -ExpandProperty Changes
```

Comment: Clear syntax, frustrating language.  It's examples like this that hurt my eyes.

Answer (score 16):

Your expression syntax isn't quite right, you need an equals ("=") between expression and the code block.

```bsh
$changesets | Select-Object `
ChangeSetId,
Owner,
Comment,
@{Name="Changes"; Expression={ $_.Changes | Select-Object ChangeType, ServerItem }}
```

If you want the nested object to be a top level elements going forward you could also do...

```bsh
$changesets | Select-Object `
ChangeSetId,
Owner,
Comment,
@{Name="ChangeType"; Expression={ $_.Changes.ChangeType}},
@{Name="ServerItem"; Expression={ $_.Changes.ServerItem }}
```

Comment: this should be the top answer, much neater

Answer (score 5):

I would probably unroll the inner collection and output once for each item in the inner collection. Something like this (not tested):

```
$changesets | foreach-object {
  $changeSetItem = $_
  $changeSetItem.Changes | foreach-object {
    $changeItem = $_
    new-object PSObject -property @{
      "ChangeSetId" = $changeSetItem.ChangeSetId
      "Owner" = $changeSetItem.Owner
      "Comment" = $changeSetItem.Comment
      "ChangeType" = $changeItem.ChangeType
      "ServerItem" = $changeItem.ServerItem
    }
  }
}
```

Bill

Comment: Appreciate the effort to provide what looks like a valid answer, would appreciate even more a quick test to confirm it does, or a comment from some other reader who tried it.

Answer (score 3):

Or, compress the array of changes into a string:

```
$changesets = ConvertFrom-Json '[{"ChangeSetId":1,"Owner":"foo","Comment":"bar","Changes":[{"ChangeType":"la", "ServerItem":"some"}, {"ChangeType":"so", "ServerItem":"stuff"}]}, {"ChangeSetId":2, "Owner":"bar", "Comment":"baz", "Changes":[{"ChangeType":"ti", "ServerItem":"other"}, {"ChangeType":"doh", "ServerItem":"stuff"}]}]'
$changesets | % {`
    [pscustomobject]@{
    ChangeSetId = $_.ChangeSetId
    Owner       = $_.Owner
    Comment     = $_.Comment
    Changes     = ($_.Changes | Select @{Name = "foo"; Expression = {$_.ChangeType + ' ' + $_.ServerItem}} | Select -ExpandProperty foo) -join "; "
  }
}
```

```
ChangeSetId Owner Comment Changes
----------- ----- ------- -------
          1 foo   bar     la some; so stuff
          2 bar   baz     ti other; doh stuff
```